# Retrieving value of visible element using java

Tags: java, html, dom, servlets

I have two elements with name `price1` [BTW I know that having duplicate IDs is against standards, is this the same with NAME?]

```
<TR CLASS="Blocks" id="p_priceKILO" style="display: none ;">
   <TD>Price:</TD>
   <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" name="price1">$/kilo</TD>
</TR>
<TR CLASS="Blocks" id="p_pricePOUND" style="display: none ;">
    <TD>Price:</TD>
    <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" name="price1">$/pound</TD>
</TR>
```

Only one of these rows will be visible at one time (using javascript)

I use the following java code to retrieve `price1`

```
public PricePosition(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.price1=StringFunctions.StringToDouble(request
                .getParameter("PRICE1"));
...
```

Is there any neat way to retrieve only the visible element?

I have a workaround - calling them `price1a` and `price1b` and retrieving the correct one based on my knowledge of which one is visible, but I wondered if there was another way.

Comment: Names should be different within the same form (except when using arrays: `price1[]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use JS again: when displaying a row, rename the inner corresponding input to `displayedPrice` for example, and get this parameter server-side.

When hiding a row, don't forget to rename it back.